# Laravel Mail - New methods with interesting parameter passing

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering here by the parameter passing in the **new** Laravel Mail class. My IDE
(VSCode) also underlines the parameter and throws the following error: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'`

```
public function envelope()
{
    return new Envelope(
        subject: 'Subject', // <-- the key subject
        from: 'test@test.fr', // <-- the key from
    );
}
```

Nevertheless, it works. It's probably a new PHP specification that I don't know
yet. What is it called and does it work? And how can I teach my IDE that it is
not an error?

Answer (score 1):

you can write code in this syntax

```
public function envelope()
{
    return $this->view('mail.welcome') // <-- View File Name
        ->from('test@test.fr')
        ->subject('Subject')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s called `named parameters` in PHP 8.

Comment: Hi there. While your answer appears to be factually correct it is also very short. Are you able to expand on your answer with further details so that it can become a valuable resource in the long term?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=named+parameters+in+PHP+8&oq=named+parameters+in+PHP+8 

In my opinion, the most difficult thing in learning syntax is finding out what the technique is called.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments